# Recent Items Block Does Not Show Recent Items Unless There Are Report Results

Tags: drupal

I am having a strange issue with the Recent Items block. It does not show all the results it should unless you are on a report that is showing results.

If I am just in CiviCRM I see this.
[image]

If I go to report and refresh the results I see something more like this. [image]

I do not see any errors being generated or anything else I can put my finger on. I cannot replicate the issue in DMASTER. DMASTER is Drupal 7 and we did not have this issue in Drupal 7.

We are running running CiviCRM 5.31.1 and Drupal 8.9.10.

Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Josh

Answer (score 2):

Can you try this patch? https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-drupal-8/pull/62

More discussion in ticket https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/2387

UPDATE: should be fixed in 5.36.0

Comment: Thanks Dave! 